# How do you update a locked record in Documentum using DQL?

Tags: documentum, documentum-dql

I'm unable to update the record with `DQL` due to a lock. Is it possible to unlock the record, update it and lock it again?

I'm running the following code in `idql64.exe` on the content server.

```
UPDATE dm_document objects SET keywords = 'D' WHERE r_object_id = '90000000000000001'
GO
```

#### Error message:

> [DM_SYSOBJECT_E_LOCKED]error:
>     "The operation on  sysobject was unsuccessful because it is locked by user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by updating the `r_immutable_flag` column.

```
UPDATE dm_document(all) objects SET r_immutable_flag = 0 WHERE r_object_id = '90000000000000001'
GO 
UPDATE dm_document(all) objects SET keywords = 'D' WHERE r_object_id = '90000000000000001'
GO 
UPDATE dm_document(all) objects SET r_immutable_flag = 1 WHERE r_object_id = '90000000000000001'
GO
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to either unlock it by API, user interface or reset the attributes `r_lock_owner` and `r_lock_machine`. I would prefer using API or user interface. API command is

```
unlock,c,{object id}
```

and it can be easily scripted.

The issue is caused by a checkout - the user which is stated in the property above.

dqMan from FME is your friend!

Br, Henning

Comment: I've upvoted your answer, but I needed to use the idql64.exe

Comment: Just upvoted this answer, and I also say that is possibile not only from DqMan, but also from DA, in Tools > API Tester.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to be a member of [dm_escalated_allow_save_on_lock](https://blog.documentum.pro/2017/06/17/q-a-xiv/) group, in this case Documentum will do everything automatically.

Comment: Wow, famous Panfilov! And again useful tip! ;)